# matrixTransform на svg: неожиданное поведение

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, svg

У меня есть div, содержащий изображение SVG размером `300x300` пикселей и viewBox `1000x1000`. 
 Изображение состоит из синего прямоугольника поверх красного.
 Когда я перемещаю мышь, круг следует за положением мыши внутри изображения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все идеально, за исключением того, что когда я применяю преобразование, изменяющее перспективу и вращение, указатель мыши и центр круга больше не совпадают:

Мой код:

```js
$(function() {
 $('#image').mousemove(function(event) {
  var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
  var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = event.clientX;
  pt.y = event.clientY;
  pt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  $('#overlay').html(
   "<circle cx='" + pt.x + "' cy='" + pt.y + "' r='50' stroke='#8f00ff' fill='transparent' stroke-width='10' /></svg>"
  );
  refresh = $("#overlay").html();
  $("#overlay").html( refresh )
 });
});
function Transform() {
 $('#image').css({
  transformOrigin: '500px 500px',
  transform: 'perspective(100px) rotateX(5deg)'
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='image' tabindex='0' >
 <svg id='svgmap' width='300' height='300' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 1000 1000'>
  <rect x='0' y='0' width='1000' height='1000' fill='red' />
  <rect x='250' y='250' width='500' height='500' stroke='yellow' fill='blue' stroke-width='10' />
  <g id='overlay'></g>
 </svg>
</div>
<button onclick='Transform()'>Transform</button>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя цель - сохранить соответствие между фиолетовым центром круга и указателем мыши, даже если к объекту применено преобразование. Есть ли способ сделать это?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/58545964/7394871

Answer (score 1):

В коде `#image` - это div. Чтобы это работало, нужно применить преобразование к элементу SVG `(#svgmap)`, и преобразование должно быть преобразованием SVG.

```js
$(function() {
 $('#svgmap').mousemove(function(event) {
  var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
  var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = event.clientX;
  pt.y = event.clientY;
  pt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  $('#overlay').html(
   "<circle cx='" + pt.x + "' cy='" + pt.y + "' r='50' stroke='#8f00ff' fill='transparent' stroke-width='10' /></svg>"
  );
  refresh = $("#layer_wafer").html();
  $("#layer_wafer").html( refresh )
 });
});
function Transform() {
 svgmap.setAttributeNS(null,"transform", "skewX(-20) translate(100)");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='image' tabindex='0' >
 <svg id='svgmap' width='300' height='300' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 1000 1000' transform="">
  <rect x='0' y='0' width='1000' height='1000' fill='red' />
    
  <rect x='250' y='250' width='500' height='500' stroke='yellow' fill='blue' stroke-width='10' />
  <g id='overlay'></g>
 </svg>
</div>
<button onclick='Transform()'>Transform</button>
```

Я понимаю, что желательно преобразование 3D CSS, но это (по крайней мере, на данный момент) не работает.

Это статья, где можно [прочитать больше о 3D преобразованиях в SVG](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch11-3d.html). Цитирую из этой статьи:

> Все функции трехмерного преобразования, описанные в этом разделе, должны рассматриваться как «будущие»